# Geting Organization name for a Exchange Server

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-2.0, exchange-server-2010

I am having a environment made up of multiple exchange servers and they are split as 3 organizations. 
I am using Get-OrganizationConfig to get the list of Organizations. 
Then I am using command: Get-ExchangeServer to get list of all the exchange Servers. 
But I am not able to get which server belongs to which Organization. 
As per my understanding each server will belong to a organization. 
Can anyone tell me how can I find the Server-Organization mapping?

I want to do this using Powershell Commandlets. A single command or small scripts will also be fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the following command, do you get the organization name in the ExchangeLegacyDN property (/o=**OrgName**/ou=...)?

```
Get-ExchangeServer | select Name,ExchangeLegacyDN
```

Comment: Actually I solved it in the same way :-). 
Only change is: We get it as DistinguishedName property and its like: 

CN=/../, CN=MY-ORG, CN=;